# Recycle AppPool

Tags: iis

Is Recycling an App Pool programatically the same as starting and stopping the app pool in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of, the difference being that during a recycle `http.sys` keeps the client connection alive whilst the worker process recycles and transparently routes new requests to the new worker process once it's started.

Also IIS (6 and 7) defaults to using "Overlapped Recycling". What this means is that IIS will start a new worker process before it shuts down the old worker process. Once the new process is started all new requests are directed to the new process.

If you stop and start the application pool you will dump all of your client connections and users may receive a Service Unavailable message whilst the new pool is being started.

Comment: Yes, I get the difference. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Additional differences are:

1. You can do recycle to your application pool only, while  stop & start influences all application pools.
2. When you are asking to recycle you have time to finalize your work (like saving your data etc.), which is not in restart.
3. You can schedule the IIS to run the recycle job depends on specific time, after period of time, depends on your memory consumption etc..